# Moment JS date calculation from timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

How do I calculate the difference in days between now and a timestamp?

I have tried this but it returns NaN:

```
var timestamp = 1405951867,
    now = moment(),
    then = moment(timestamp),
    diff = now.diff(then, 'days');
```

Comment: Your code is working fine for me, I get proper result in the `diff` variable. Keep in mind, however, that moment.js uses timestamps in milliseconds, not in seconds.

Comment: Thanks, I multiplied the timestamp by 1000 and it works.